# Replicate logic or using existent in tests?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have some concerns about writing too much logic in the spec tests.

So let's assume we have a `student` with `statuses` and `steps`

Student statuses starts from

```
pending -> learning -> graduated -> completed
```

and steps are:

```
nil -> learning_step1 -> learning_step2 -> learning_step3 -> monitoring_step1 -> monitoring_step2
```

With each step going forward a lot of things are happening depending where you are: e.g.

```
nil -> learning_step1
```

Student status changes to `learning`
Writes an action history ( which is used by report stats )
Update a contact schedule

```
learning_step1 -> learning_step2
```

....the same...

and so ..... until

```
learning_step3 -> monitoring_step1
```

Student status changes to `graduated`
Writes different action histories ( which is used by report stats )
Update a contact schedule

and when

```
monitoring_step2 -> there is no next step
```

Student status changes to `completed`
Writes different action histories ( which is used by report stats )
Delete any contact schedule

So imagine that I need a test case of a `completed` student, I would have to think all the possibilities that may come and achieve that student as `completed` and also I can forget to write an action history and will mess with the reports.

Or ....

Using an already implemented class:

```
# assuming we have like in the above example 5 steps I do

StepManager.new(student).proceed # goes status learning and step1
StepManager.new(student).proceed
StepManager.new(student).proceed
StepManager.new(student).proceed # goes status graduated and monitoring1
StepManager.new(student).proceed # this will proceed the student in the 5th step which is monitoring2
StepManager.new(student).next_step # here will go completed
```

or to make my job easier with something like:

```
StepManager.new(student).proceed.proceed.proceed.proceed.proceed.proceed
```

or

```
StepManager.new(student).complete_student # which in background does the same thing
```

And by doing that I am sure I will never miss something. But then the tests wouldn't be so clear about what I am doing.

So should I replicate the logic or using my classes?

Comment: This question is too broad and confusing for anyone to provide a reasonable answer.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or this could get flagged.  Furthermore you're not doing TDD correctly.  You should have each method isolated and write a unit tests.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512504/tdd-how-to-start-really-thinking-tdd#2512873

Comment: @lacostenycoder yes I agree and I have for StepManager but when you want to test a method which generates a report and in order to get something on that reports you must call complex code? ... I will read your post.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a state machine. Look into something like `aasm`. You may also want to look into `factory_bot` for a way to set up more complex test fixtures.

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan it sounds like you need help with design patterns. You should probably be storing state of the students progress in a database. As each step gets completed, update the state in the database.  There are many ways to build fixtures and/or factories for testing state. In Rails you might use `factory_girl` or as @Drenmi suggested https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot

Comment: @lacostenycoder yep, this is what I am doing now, on a specific step I have a different status and I am already handling this with `StepManager` as I said. But attention! Each next step, comes with additional inserts and updates in database beside the status update, as I said I am saving schedules, action_histories, and let's say for example I want an student at `completed` status. Imagine that I have to insert 5 action histories etc. As I said each next step is not just changing status and current step. Yes I use factory girl but never thought to achieve this with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use TDD best practices.  In a rails project for example, write unit tests for your models and controller actions.  Same for services.  Test each unit for it's expectations.  If you need more complex data state to check, it's recommended to use factories using https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot or https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails if you're using rails.